# What is the difference between "Art" and "Weise"?

Tags: difference, meaning

I think everyone knows the term "die Art und Weise" like in

> Die Art und Weise, wie er entlassen wurde, gefällt mir nicht.

But mostly this usage seems redundant to me. I guess in 99% of cases one could have omitted *Weise*.

> Die Art, wie er entlassen wurde, gefällt mir nicht.

But then again, *Art* and *Weise* are not interchangeable, e.g.:

> Er hat eine nette Art.

So what is the difference between these words, especially in the context of *Art und Weise*?

PS: I am a native German speaker.

Comment: A good resource for such questions is Farrell's Dictionary of German Synonyms. See page 374 of the third edition for a discussion of this expression.

Comment: Deine Muttersprache ist also Deutsch. Und du bist hier in einem Forum, dessen Thema die deutsche Sprache ist. Und du stellst eine Frage über eine Besonderheit der deutsche Sprache. Also warum zum Teufel stellst du deine Frage in einer Fremdsprache?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Aus dem selben Grund, wieso viele Fragen hier auf Englisch gestellt und beantwortet werden: Das internationale Publikum. Außerdem ist es mir ja vermutlich freigestellt, in welcher Sprache ich Fragen stelle:

http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-language-should-the-questions-be-written-in

Comment: Wenn man fragt: »Warum machst du das?«, und als Antwort erhält: »Ich darf es mir ja wohl selber aussuchen«, dann ist das zwar ein Hinweis auf die Legitimität der Wahl (die ja gar nicht angezweifelt wurde), beantwortet die Frage aber nicht, weil kein Grund für die konkret getroffene Wahl genannt wurde. Der Hinweis auf das internationale Publikum ist ein Grund der die Frage beantwortet, aber das internationale Publikum besucht diese Seite um DEUTSCH zu lernen. Ich halte es für akzeptabel Fragen in englischer Sprache zu stellen wenn man schlecht Deutsch spricht, aber das trifft auf dich nicht zu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Art und Weise" ist ein stehender Begriff (ein Idiom könnte man sagen), der nichts anders bedeutet als "Weise". In der Antike war es ein stilistischer Kunstgriff für ein griechisches Wort, das im Lateinischen fehlte, ein Wortpaar zu wählen, das dem griechischen Wort sozusagen von beiden Seiten näher kam. So ein Doppelbegriff wurde Hendiadyoin genannt (griechisch: eins durch zwei). Der Sinn solcher Doppelbegriffe ist aber im Grunde nur ein einziges Wort. Und "Art und Weise" ist ein Hendiadyoin nach antikem Vorbild.

http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendiadyoin

Answer (score 1):

One could likewise omit "Art", as they are synonymous in this context. The difference mostly lies in their other meanings; see the [corresponding](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Art) Duden [entries](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Weise_Methode_Melodie_Lied).

Answer (score 0):

They are very similar, I agree. If I were to explain a difference between the two:

I think "Art" is more like a personal way to do things. It is more connected to a character/person.
Whereas "Weise" feels more like a process that is applied to someone; when you are talking about a certain method of doing something.